# Java Thread Sync

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

I have a class Shop. In main i create 3 shop objects in main

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(shop1);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(shop2);
Thread thread3 = new Thread(shop3);


threads.add(thread1);
threads.add(thread2);
threads.add(thread3);

for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.start();
}
```

run method in the shop class

```
@Override
public void run() {

   for(int day=0;day<=360;++day) {
      if (day% 30 == 0) {
         delivery();
     }

CODE...
   }
}
```

I would like threads to sync every 30 days. So every 30 days threads are waiting for each other.

It would be easiest to use Thread.join() but how can I use it when I'm in run().

I was also thinking about doing instead of 360 days, 12 times 30 days

```
public void run() {

   for(int day=0;day<30;++day) {
      if (day% 30 == 0) {
         delivery();
     }

CODE...
```

and use in main join() but then there is a problem how to restart the method.

What can i do to synchronize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get familiar with `CyclicBarrier` class.

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

Note that you can optionally define a barrierAction, which is executed by last  thread reaching the barrier.

See tutorial [CyclicBarrier in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cyclic-barrier)